# How to add new fields to document in Cloudant without losing existing ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudant

I am attempting to add new fields to a document I have in Cloudant based on user input, however when I do an insert I am overwriting the document and losing existing fields, unless I send them with the `insert`.

For example, I have one command that performs a query to Cloudant to receive a document, and returns me the `_id, _rev, name and special_id` fields. This document gets passed to a new command that appends a field, such as `favorite_food`, through an insert (and yes I am using `_rev`).

Now, the user inputs another command, like "add school". The process starts over, I query Cloudant, and the query I have returns me the `_id, _rev, name, and special_id`. I append a `school` field to the doc, do an `insert`, but then I check the document and `favorite_food` is gone.

Is there a param that I can pass to the Cloudant `insert` function to tell it to actually perform an update and not an overwrite?

FYI this is running on Node and using the [node-cloudant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant) package. In the docs I can't find any more details about params, and a typical insert looks like:

```
cloudantDb.insert(doc, params, function(error, response) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log("success", response);
    resolve(response);
  } else {
    console.log("error", error);
    reject(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to say for sure. There is no magic parameter. In Cloudant, there is no difference between create, update and delete -- they're all essentially creating a revision. You can't "patch" the JSON doc, you need to provide the whole thing, every time. Here's an example:

```
# Create a new document
curl -XPOST -H 'content-type:application/json' \
    'https://skruger.cloudant.com/testdb' -d '{"name":"stefan"}'
{"ok":true,"id":"5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c","rev":"1-a0f0b27e1069f45cc121dfe5dc08f280"}

# Add a field
curl -XPUT -H 'content-type:application/json' \
 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/testdb/5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c' \
  -d '{"_id":"5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c", "_rev":"1-a0f0b27e1069f45cc121dfe5dc08f280", "name":"stefan", "fish":"pike pearch"}'
{"ok":true,"id":"5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c","rev":"2-7c3ea3603c3e16962c7b33f50becc771"}

# Fetch it again
curl 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/testdb/5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c' 
{"_id":"5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c","_rev":"2-7c3ea3603c3e16962c7b33f50becc771","name":"stefan","fish":"pike pearch"}

# And another new field
curl -XPUT -H 'content-type:application/json' \
 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/testdb/5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c' \
 -d '{"_id":"5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c", "_rev":"2-7c3ea3603c3e16962c7b33f50becc771", "name":"stefan", "fish":"pike pearch", "sport":"tennis"}'
 {"ok":true,"id":"5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c","rev":"3-e0f4d1ab1a47b046ea90a0fbbf34ff36"}

# Fetch again    
curl 'https://skruger.cloudant.com/testdb/5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c'
{"_id":"5309a1784a9cc45d498e8170af7dcc3c","_rev":"3-e0f4d1ab1a47b046ea90a0fbbf34ff36","name":"stefan","fish":"pike pearch","sport":"tennis"}
```